# Can't save output of particular command in particular environment (cron)

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, tee

My crontab is not producing logs for a *particular* command I'm using to monitor my network; other commands work fine.

```
* * * * *    /usr/bin/COMMAND opt1 opt2 >> /home/pi/LOG.log 2>&1
```

The log file is created, but the output of the command does not log. The command and logging works fine when run in it in the terminal. I've tried copying the cron environment and running the command manually:

With `crontab -e`, I added:

```
* * * * * env > ~/cronenv
```

Then I run:

```
env - `cat ~/cronenv` /bin/sh
/usr/bin/COMMAND opt1 opt2
```

The COMMAND outputs as expected, but as soon as I try to log the output, I get empty logs:

```
/usr/bin/COMMAND opt1 opt2 > /home/pi/LOG.log 2>&1
/usr/bin/COMMAND opt1 opt2 | tee /home/pi/LOG.log 2>&1
```

Switching my shell in `crontab -e` to `SHELL=/bin/bash` also has no effect.

Not sure if it's relevant, but the command I'm struggling with takes several seconds to run, outputs in color with somewhat fancy formatting, unicode characters, etc. when I run it in the terminal, but it still logs fine. When I run it from the `cronenv` I created, it does not display in color, but displays in much the same way it does when I save it to a log from terminal.

EDIT:

This is working in the `~/cronenv` environment I made, but the log is created but empty when run through cron (as before):

```
/usr/bin/unbuffer /usr/bin/COMMAND opt1 opt2 > /home/pi/LOG.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Perhaps your job is failing and producing no output for the logging to capture. Can you test a script that just lists a directory and capture the output in a file? The system crontab runs as root with different environment variables. Have you taken that in to account? Are you using a user crontab? Does your script run in a terminal when you have switched to the root user?

Comment: So I've copied the cron environment to my home directory, and 1) the command runs and outputs as expected but 2) I cannot get it to save these results to a file, i.e. in the interactive environment I've made. That it was a cron environment is almost irrelevant at this point--what could it be about this environment where I can successfully run this particular command and get an output, but the usual redirection commands seem to have no effect (but redirection works fine for other commands)? I.e. what could it be about the command itself where a change in environment prevents saving the output?

Comment: I've just tried this on my system. Using "crontab -e" I added a job "* * * * * /home/john/lstest.txt". lstest.txt contained  "#!/bin/sh" "set -e" "cd /home/john" "ls >> ls.txt" "exit". When I created lstest.txt I did a chmod a+x lstest.txt to ensure all users can run the script. Cron did its thing and the script wrote the directory listing to ls.txt every minute.Does this work on your system?

Comment: Yes that works fine. The problem is there is something about this specific command. I've verified it runs, but in cron it either doesn't output anything to the log or runs without error and doesn't output anything.

Comment: Have you tried running the command in a script rather than have the whole thing on a single line in the crontab? Could the structure of “command space option space option space redirection” be misinterpreted? Can you run it twice, once with each option? Could you add a step before and after the command to output the date or “starting job” then “ending job”